# What year was the song Prelude no 5 by Heitor Villa-Lobos song written?

Tags: classical-music

can anyone tell me what year the song Prelude no 5 by Heitor Villa-Lobos was originally written. I need the original song year and not an arrangement of it.

Comment: Just looking up "Heitor Villa-Lobos" on Wikipedia would answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=tp6LO9n1TrIC&pg=PA113&dq=cinq%20preludes%20heitor%20villa%20lobos&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwB2oVChMI3YmezPD5yAIVSC8mCh3JhQvy#v=onepage&q=cinq%20preludes%20heitor%20villa%20lobos&f=false) I can [find](http://imslp.org/wiki/Preludes,_W419_(Villa-Lobos,_Heitor)#General_Information) including [multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heitor_Villa-Lobos) Wikipedia [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelude_No._1_(Villa-Lobos)) seems to indicate that it was written in 1940. The sources listed out:

- [Page 113](https://books.google.com/books?id=tp6LO9n1TrIC&pg=PA113&dq=cinq%20preludes%20heitor%20villa%20lobos&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwB2oVChMI3YmezPD5yAIVSC8mCh3JhQvy#v=onepage&q=cinq%20preludes%20heitor%20villa%20lobos&f=false) of **The Guitar from the Renaissance to the Present Day**
- The [Petrucci Music Library wiki](http://imslp.org/wiki/Preludes,_W419_(Villa-Lobos,_Heitor)#General_Information), which catalogues public domain compositions.
- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heitor_Villa-Lobos) for the composer
- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelude_No._1_(Villa-Lobos)) for the first prelude

Since I can't seem to find anything that offers a different year or disputes 1940 as the year of composition, I'd be inclined to say that this is evidence enough that Villa-Lobos wrote his five preludes, including "Prelude No. 5", in 1940.